# evt.target.content stops function in web browser only

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, bitmap

I am getting an image from url and converting it to be used as scrub images.
This works fine inside flash using test movie (cmd + return)

But once I have the swf file embedded on a website it stops working.

*Note Utils.BrowserErrorTrace just outputs to the console on both web and flash*

```
    private function loadComplete(evt:Event):void
    {
        Utils.BrowserLogTrace("loading complete");
        Utils.BrowserLogTrace("line 1");

        var loaderInfo:LoaderInfo = evt.target as LoaderInfo;
        Utils.BrowserLogTrace("line 2");

        var loadedBitmap:Bitmap = loaderInfo.content as Bitmap;
        Utils.BrowserLogTrace("line 3"); 
        // line 3 is where it stops working

        this.loadedSpriteSheet = new SpriteSheet(loadedBitmap,Settings.scrubImageWidth,Settings.scrubImageHeight);
        Utils.BrowserLogTrace("line 4");

        Settings.scrubImagesFound = true;
        Utils.BrowserLogTrace("line 5");

    }
```

This is the output from **inside flash**:

> log - loading complete
>
> log - line 1
>
> log - line 2
>
> log - line 3
>
> log - line 4
>
> log - line 5
>
> log - line 6

and the output from inside a **web browser** (google chrome):

> loading complete
>
> line 1
>
> line 2

I do not get any errors when in the web browser just using stack tracing I can see it stops at "line 3".

Also if I call "evt.target.content"

So my question is, why does it work on the test view inside as3 and not as a swf file on a web browser?

How can I get errors out?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed Caused by SecurityError: Error #2122

Updated my loader to use loader context

```
var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext();
                loaderContext.checkPolicyFile = true;
                loaderContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;

                var loader:Loader = new Loader();
                loader.load(url,loaderContext);
```